# Why jackson is not serializing this?

Tags: jackson, retrofit2, lombok

```
@Data
public class IdentificacaoBiometricaDto {
    private Integer cdIdentifBiom;
    private String nrMatricula;
    private String deImpressaoDigital;
    private Integer cdFilialAtualizacao;
}
```

I am using retrofit 2.6.1, jackson 2.9.9 and lombok 1.8.10.

The exception is:

```
    Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class br.com.clamed.modelo.loja.dto.central.IdentificacaoBiometricaDto and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1191)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:313)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:71)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.serialize(UnknownSerializer.java:33)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:400)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1392)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter._configAndWriteValue(ObjectWriter.java:1120)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValueAsBytes(ObjectWriter.java:1017)
    at retrofit2.converter.jackson.JacksonRequestBodyConverter.convert(JacksonRequestBodyConverter.java:34)
    at retrofit2.converter.jackson.JacksonRequestBodyConverter.convert(JacksonRequestBodyConverter.java:24)
    at retrofit2.ParameterHandler$Body.apply(ParameterHandler.java:355)
    ... 14 more
```

The object mapper:

```
    return new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new ParameterNamesModule())
                             .registerModule(new Jdk8Module())
                             .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())
                             .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
```

I am setting all fields, when passing it to a request body, retrofit fails because jackson could not serialize the object.

Retrofit call:

```
@POST("/usuario/v1.0/cadastraBiometria")
Call<IdentificacaoBiometricaDto> cadastraBiometria(@Body IdentificacaoBiometricaDto identificacaoBiometricaDto);
```

Rest service:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/usuario")
public class UsuarioController {

    @PostMapping(value = "/v1.0/cadastraBiometria")
    public ResponseEntity<IdentificacaoBiometricaDto> cadastraBiometria(@RequestBody IdentificacaoBiometricaDto identificacaoBiometricaDto) {
    }
}
```

**Update:**

- If I change the retrofit converter to Gson it works;
- If I serialize it using Jackson directly, it works;
- Removing lombok makes no difference;

Comment: Could you show how do you create `IdentificacaoBiometricaDto` object and invoke `API` method? Could you show `API` method declaration?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. The biometric reader library was causing this. For some reason it's incompatible with openjdk-11 and is causing all sort of unrelated problems.

Yes, very weird. But the lib is very poorly done.